# Set li element class active in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ul of class `items` and li elements of class `item` each. The li elements has a and i would like to set a particular link from the li as active . The li has varying ids like

```
<ul class="items">
  <li id="id1" class="active hover ">id1 </li>
  <li id="id2" class="active hover ">id2 </li>
  <li id="id3" class="active hover ">id3 </li>
  <li id="id4" class="active hover ">id4 </li>
</ul>
```

In my case i want to set id 3 example as acive . So i use the id like below.

```
if(active.item) {
    var patt = new RegExp("id2");
    if(page.language() === 'FR' && patt.test(active.item.id)){
        document.getElementById("id2").addClass('active');
        document.getElementById("id2").addClass('hover');
    }
    else{
        active.item.addClass('active');
        active.item.addClass('hover'); 
    }
}
```

I print my active.item in the console and it gives me below

```
console.log("Active item is ", active.item);
```

The result

> [li#id2.item.fr-hide, prevObject: _.fn.init[1], context: a.link.pjaxload]0: li#top2.item.fr-hide.active.hovercontext: a.link.pjaxloadlength: 1prevObject: _.fn.init[1]**proto**: _[0].

My id is id2. However, my the active and hover cssClass are not added to my element. Please where do i go wrong . Before i did

```
"id2".test(active.item.id)
```

The above returns error saying "id2".test is not a function. I changed to the patt variable above for a test.

Please why isn't my active and hover classes added ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because addClass() is a jquery method. you are trying to apply it on a dom element.
Try this

```
$("#id2").addClass('active');
```

See this example,

```
$("li").hover(function () {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5bjrtfzc/7/)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand completely what you are trying to achieve, but as to why your `active` and `hover` classes are not being added here lies the problem:

```
document.getElementById("id2").addClass('active');
document.getElementById("id2").addClass('hover');
```

Here you are mixing JavaScript and jQuery. It should be either JavaScript like this:

```
document.getElementById("id2").setAttribute("class", "active hover");
```

Or jQuery like this:

```
$("#id2").addClass('active hover');
```

Answer (score 0):

As Anoop Joshi suggsted you could use jQuery.

If you're not using jQuery however:

```
document.getElementById("id2").className += " active hover"
```

You can also use `classList` with `add` and `remove`

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList